# Laplace's equation, integral, tends to steady state?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

If $v(x,y)$ solves Laplace's equation $v_{xx} + v_{yy} = 0$ on a bounded domain $S$, and $u(x,y,t)$ solves $u_t = u_{xx} + u_{yy}$ on $S$, with $u=v$ on $\partial S$ for all $t$, one can show that $\phi(t):= \int_S (u-v)^2$ is decreasing in $t$. Is it true that $\phi(t) \to 0$ as $t\to \infty$? Will appreciate any hints, thanks.

(It probably isn't needed, but for the first part, $\phi'(t) = \int_S 2(u-v)\nabla^2 u = \int_S 2(u-v)\nabla^2 (u-v)$ $= \int_S \nabla^2 (u-v)^2 - 2\|\nabla(u-v)\|^2 \leq \oint_{\partial S} \nabla(u-v) \cdot dz = 0$.)

Comment: @127.0.9.6 $\phi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, so the norm is the usual norm on $\mathbb{R}$. I wasn't given any more assumptions on $v$...

Answer (score 0):

The computations become a little cleaner if you introduce $w=u-v$, which also solves the heat equation and has zero boundary conditions. You have shown that 
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_S w^2 \le -\int_S |\nabla w|^2 \tag{1}$$
What is needed is to relate the right hand side to $\int_S w^2$. This is what the Poincaré inequality does: 
$$\int_S w^2 \le C \int_S |\nabla w|^2 \tag{2}$$
Combine (2) with (1), and you'll get a differential inequality from which the desired conclusion follows quickly.

> Further hint: $e^{t/C}\phi(t)$ is non-increasing.

Comment: Ok... I haven't learnt anything about Poincare inequality or Sobolev spaces yet, will return to this later, thanks.